# BigQuery: how to count specific values in a REPEATED field?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, unnest

I have a STRING REPEATED field in a **BigQuery** table.

this is a list of rows for such field:

- "A"
- "A","C","E"
- "B,"E"
- "A","B","D"
- "D","E"

How can I **count** the total number of occurrencies of all single values?

I tried with "GROUP BY", but it seems that it's not possible to GROUP BY a REPEATED field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to UNNEST and then count:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM T, UNNEST(array_column) AS x
GROUP BY x
```